# Is there any API avialable in j2me through which we can access the sensor "accelerometer"?

Tags: java-me

I want to make a game based on the sensor accelerator. Is there any API available in j2me through which we can access the accelerator sensor. or is there any other idea regarding the same ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's such API - [called JSR-256](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=256). Try to Google and you'll find appropriate resources.